# Prestashop shipping cost when user has more address

Tags: php, prestashop

I have created a Prestashop shipping module in PHP, where the distance between two locations is calculated based on Google Maps API.

When the user has just one address, everything is ok, but when he has two or more addresses and he select the second one to deliver the package, the shipping cost is calculated for the first address (`$customer_address[0]`).

I want the right result. When I select the second item from combo box, shipping cost will be calculated based on the second item address.

I've tried to do this after obtain results from database, but isn't working.

[Here is the code!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3SaeoPm0z8QazA5MGRTcWNSd0E/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You must get address from cart:

```
$customer_address = $params->id_address_delivery;
```

when a customer select an address from saved addresses prestashop use this address to calculate shipping cost.